# Cannot construct KafkaProducer on brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

```
Produce(String broker,String topic,int count){
        this.topic=topic;
        props.put("bootstrap.servers",broker);
        props.put("buffer.memory",67108864);
        props.put("key.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    }
    public void run(){
        InetAddress ia=null;
        try {
            ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        }catch (Exception e){
            logger.error(e);
        }
        List<KafkaProducer<String,String>> producers=new ArrayList<KafkaProducer<String,String>>();
        System.out.println(6);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            try {
                KafkaProducer<String, String> pro = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
                System.out.println(6.5);
                producers.add(pro);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(7);
        ...
    }
```

I'm working on produce some sample data to Kafka.

The cluster is CDH 5.5.0 and kafka version is 0.10.2.

Once I was able to run this to produce data to topicpartitions.
For producing to topics from remote I set the advertised.host.name to the hostname of each broker and then I can produce to topics from clients outside the cluster.

But I can't run the same code on any brokers from then on,even if I remove the advertised.host.name as it used to be.

As I try to run this as Jar on any server in hadoop cluster(7 servers,3 as Kafka broker) except the one runs zookeeper, System.out won't reach "6.5",means the construction of KafkaProducer is blocked and no exceptions thrown.

Have someone met something like this before?

Comment: It's more weird that running kafka-perf-test on any broker with the same bootstrap.servers configuration will successfully produce messages to configured topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing because it's caused by java version difference.
I build it with jdk1.8 while it's jdk1.6 on cluster.